# Graphics.drawimage doesn't work

Tags: java, graphics, drawimage

The following code should display a red rectangle, but it doesn't work in fact. However, if I uncomment `paint` method, it works;It seems the `g.drawImage(app.img, 0, 0, f)` in `main` method doesn't work. What's the problem and solution?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferByte;

public class LoadImageApp extends Component {
    private static final int SCREEN_WIDTH = 400;
    private static final int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 300;
    BufferedImage img;

//    public void paint(Graphics g) {
//        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
//    }

    public LoadImageApp() {
        img = new BufferedImage(SCREEN_WIDTH,
                SCREEN_HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
        byte[] b = ((DataBufferByte) img.getRaster().getDataBuffer())
                .getData();
        for (int i = 0; i < img.getWidth() * img.getHeight(); i++) {
            b[i * 3] = 0;
            b[i * 3 + 1] = 0;
            b[i * 3 + 2] = (byte)0xff;
        }

    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (img == null) {
            return new Dimension(100, 100);
        } else {
            return new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame f = new JFrame("Load Image Sample");

        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        LoadImageApp app = new LoadImageApp();
        f.add(app);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
        Graphics g = app.getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(app.img, 0, 0, f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working, but it may look like nothing happens because `g.drawImage(app.img, 0, 0, f);` is only called once when your main method starts, and the image is hidden again as soon as the window updates.

To fix this you ether need to add an image to a component so that it auto updates/paints, or to override the `public void paint(Graphics g)` method like you mentioned.

Edit:
Don't forge to call super on your components paint method if you do stick with the paint override, otherwise any child components or other paint related items will not be drawn.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
}
```

If the image is a background the you could put `super.paintComponents` after `g.drawimage`